# How determine the compression of a beam with a concentrated end load in the x axis?

Tags: beam, deflection

I'm studying Electronics Engineering so I have almost no background in mechanics, just a little of statics and dynamics. I have recently started an internship in an investigation center where they make microelectromechanical systems (MEMS). I was asked to know the deformation in $y$- and $x$-axes for a cantilever beam with a concentrated end load. I have more interest in the vectorial mechanics rather than the material mechanics.

I have done research in Minhang Bao's book *[Analysis and Design Principles of MEMS Devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444516166)*, where I found that the maximum displacement at the free end is: 
$$w(L) = \dfrac{4FL^3}{EI}$$
if the load is on the $y$-axis.

But I couldn't find any information related to the compression in the $x$-axis. I came up with the idea of using a similar triangles approach but think that won't be so accurate.

Comment: A diagram of the loading scenario you're looking at would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I'm assuming you mean this:

[image]

In this case, the axial deflection at the free end is equal to

$$ w_x(L) = \dfrac{FL}{EA} $$

This can be trivially obtained by noting that the compressive stress is equal to
$$\sigma = \dfrac{F}{A}$$

And, by [Hooke's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) we know that the relationship between stress and deformation (assuming linear elasticity) is equal to
$$\begin{align}
\sigma &= E\epsilon \\
\therefore \epsilon &= \dfrac{\sigma}{E}
\end{align}$$
where $E$ is the elastic modulus of the material.

The deflection at the free end is equal to
$$w(L) = \int_0^L\epsilon(x)\text{d}x$$
which, for a member under uniform stress such as this one, simplifies to
$$w(L) = \epsilon L$$
therefore, using the equations above, we get
$$ w_x(L) = \dfrac{FL}{EA} $$